# How to use a reference design in datasheet?

Tags: microcontroller, pcb-design, schematics, bluetooth-low-energy, soc

I'm trying to gain a better understanding on what [this](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-42426-SmartConnect-SAMB11-SOC_Datasheet.pdf) is and how to use it. I know this is a datasheet for SAMB11 SoC, more specifically the reference design on page 50 is what I'm inquiring about.

1. In a general sense, is a reference design the simplest/fastest way to get the target component up and running, or is this one of many examples of how to implement this SoC?
2. Is it safe to use this as a starting point depending on how I'm using it? I guess I'm wondering when this circuit is built what will it give me?

Thanks for your patience and time.

Comment: Reference design is an example of using the part. Use it as you wish.

Comment: Depends on the data sheet. May be simplest, may be the most common use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In a general sense, is a reference design the simplest/fastest way to
>   get the target component up and running, or is this one of many
>   examples of how to implement this SoC?

Every manufacturer is free to make their own decisions of course, but generally a "Reference Design" is the design that the manufacturer used when they were compiling the documentation. Thus, the performance, features and behaviour described in the rest of the datasheet is *with reference to* the Reference Design.

In practice, that tends to mean that it's a good example of how to get everything running on the IC.

> Is it safe to use this as a starting point depending on how I'm using
>   it?

Oh definitely. Unless you have something else to go by (eg. experience or similar design) the reference design is always an excellent place to start. It's possible you could come up with a more efficient/streamlined design if your requirements are narrower than everything the IC offers, but you can always leave bits out or re-design down the track.

> I guess I'm wondering when this circuit is built what will it give me?

It'll give you a functional circuit that demonstrates all the functionality described in the datasheet.

Note that building this circuit correctly is not trivial. The matching network in particular takes some design nous. At a glance the rest is straight-forward and well documented - just be sure to follow the comments!

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. Much appreciated. From what everyone has said, I'm convinced that the reference design is a solid way to turn the chip on and enable it for supporting Rf, or any other peripheral circuitry that may be needed.

Answer (score 6):

Since this is RF IC, following schematic won't be enough.

When building circuits the first time, it's always recommended to follow design guide/ reference schematic as much as you can. That will be a huge step forward to making your circuit work.

Since this is RF stuff, you need to go a step further. Being familiar how to interface antenna and which stackup to use is basics. There is a lot material on that topic here. Perhaps there is a reference layout somewhere that you can follow(Nordic gives you Altium project so you could basically copy/paste the layout which is nice if you are beginner)

Comment: Yeah. Time spent studying the manufacturers' evaluation board layout is never wasted.

Comment: yeah seriously, I've been playing around with Cypress semiconductors Eval kit. What's cool about that one, and I'm sure many others, is that they have an IDE and all kinds of example code to use. I'm doing a lot of work with BLE and I"m trying to understand coding the BLE stack. Thanks again for your input. @Bip